# Web scraping: scrape urls in table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the website below: (please note it is in Korean)
https://law.go.kr/lsSc.do?menuId=1&subMenuId=15&tabMenuId=81&query=

I need to scrape all the contents of each of the links in the column '법령명' which is right next to the index column (please see below images for reference), but the links don't seem to be unique. They all seem to have url of https://law.go.kr/lsSc.do?menuId=1&subMenuId=15&tabMenuId=81&query=#undefined but the url doesn't seem to work either for creating a soup.

I wonder what might be a problem here, or if scraping these might not be possible at all.

[website_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcjXH.png)

[part_needs_scraping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRmuN.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what you have already tried providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded with Javascript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. You can however simulate the Ajax requests with `requests` module. For example:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://law.go.kr/lsSc.do?menuId=1&subMenuId=15&tabMenuId=81&query="

menu_url = "https://law.go.kr/lsScListR.do?" + url.split("?")[-1]
content_url = "https://law.go.kr/lsInfoR.do"

data = {
    "q": "*",
    "outmax": "50",
    "p18": "0",
    "p19": "1,3",
    "pg": "1",
    "fsort": "10,41,21,31",
    "lsType": "null",
    "section": "lawNm",
    "lsiSeq": "0",
    "p9": "2,4",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(menu_url, data=data).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select(".left_list_bx a[onclick]"):
    if "lsViewWideAll" not in a["onclick"]:
        continue

    lsiSeq, efYd, *_ = re.findall(r"\d+", a["onclick"])

    data = {
        "lsiSeq": lsiSeq,
        "efYd": efYd,
        "chrClsCd": "010202",
        "vSct": "*",
        "efGubun": "Y",
        "ancYnChk": "0",
    }

    s = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.post(content_url, data=data).content, "html.parser"
    )
    print(s.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n"))
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
판례
연혁
위임행정규칙
규제
생활법령
10ㆍ27법난 피해자의 명예회복 등에 관한 법률

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Please could I ask how you found the urls for the menu and content respectively?

Comment: Also, could you please help point to how you were able to get the data dictionary? Thanks!

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could point to some hints - thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the website using the onClick method on these rows. So the only way to scrape this is to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), since requests and beautiful soup can't evaluate javascript functions.